# Building Boost from sources on Linux

Tags: boost, build

#### Description:

I am trying to build the Boost library (1.68) from sources on Ubuntu 18.04.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html
https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_68_0.html

#### Questions:

**1)** For a same version, is it equivalent to a `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`? ...which basically will install all theses deps:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:    
  libboost-all-dev libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.65-dev libboost-atomic1.65.1 libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.65-dev
  libboost-chrono1.65.1 libboost-container-dev libboost-container1.65-dev libboost-container1.65.1 libboost-context-dev
  libboost-context1.65-dev libboost-context1.65.1 libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-coroutine1.65-dev libboost-coroutine1.65.1
  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.65-dev libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.65-dev libboost-fiber-dev
  libboost-fiber1.65-dev libboost-fiber1.65.1 libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.65-dev libboost-graph-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.65.1 libboost-graph1.65-dev
  libboost-graph1.65.1 libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.65-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.65-dev
  libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.65-dev libboost-log1.65.1 libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.65-dev libboost-math1.65.1
  libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65.1 libboost-mpi1.65-dev
  libboost-mpi1.65.1 libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.65-dev libboost-numpy1.65.1 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.65-dev libboost-program-options1.65.1 libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.65-dev
  libboost-python1.65.1 libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.65-dev libboost-random1.65.1 libboost-regex-dev
  libboost-regex1.65-dev libboost-regex1.65.1 libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.65-dev
  libboost-serialization1.65.1 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.65-dev libboost-signals1.65.1 libboost-stacktrace-dev
  libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev libboost-stacktrace1.65.1 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.65-dev libboost-test-dev
  libboost-test1.65-dev libboost-test1.65.1 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.65-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.65-dev
  libboost-timer1.65.1 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev libboost-type-erasure1.65.1
  libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.65-dev libboost-wave1.65.1 libboost1.65-tools-dev
```

**2)**
I basically followed the [instructions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html):
running `./bootstrap.sh` from where I downloaded (i.e. in `/opt/boost_18_0/bootstrap.sh`)
and then `./b2`

at the end of the b2 process, it showed:

```
(...)
...updated 1275 targets...

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
    /opt/boost_1_68_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
    /opt/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib
```

I wonder why it's not located in `/usr/local` where it should according to the `bootstrap.sh` default setting for the `--prefix` option?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> 1) Is it equivalent to a sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

No. `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` will install whatever
`x.y.z` version of the boost libraries your distro (Debian, Ubuntu ...?)
has packaged as `libboost-all-dev` in the latest package updates that
you have applied to your system. On my Ubuntu 18.04 system that happens
to be 1.65.1 right now. Building and installing the tarball `boost_1_68_0.tar.bz2` that
you downloaded will of course give you version 1.68.0.

If your package manager provides a `libboost-all-dev` at version 1.68.0
(or the same version that your download as source), then building and
installing from the source tarball will provide your boost client projects with
exactly the same boost resources via compilation and linkage as installing
the `libboost-all-dev` package.

But installing that package will not
create the same directories and files in your filesystem as building and installing
the source tarball unless with `./bootstrap.sh` you configure the same installation paths
(`--prefix`, `--includedir`, `--libdir`...) as are used by the `apt` package installation.
So, e.g. My `apt` installation of `libboost-all-dev` installs the boost
headers under `/usr/include/boost` and the boost library binaries under
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. But by default the source tarball installation
will place the headers under `/usr/local/include/boost` and the library binaries
under `/usr/local/lib`.

For a given version of boost, the only other difference between
`apt install libboost-all-dev` and a source build and install with the default install
prefix (`/usr/local`) is that after a source build and install, if you wish to link and
run your programs with the boost *shared* (not static) libraries, you will need to run
`$ sudo ldconfig` (in any directory) to update the OS loader's dynamic linkage cache.
`apt install libboost-all-dev` will update the `ldconfig` cache automatically.

> I wonder why it's not located in /usr/local where it should according to the bootstrap.sh default setting for the --prefix option?

That is because you have just *built* boost, but not installed it. You ran

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

in `/opt/boost_1_68_0`, and when it finished it told you (amoung other things)

```
Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2
```

So then, as you say, you ran `./b2`. That is, *to build*. And when building
had finished, you saw the output you've posted. It tells you that your successful boost build
can now be used in client projects by specifying the compiler search option `-I/opt/boost_1_68_0`
and the linker search option `-L/opt/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib`. You can your use boost libraries like that,
from the *build directory* `/opt/boost_1_68_0`, *without installing them*. This would be what you'd have to
do if you didn't have root privilege on your system.

But if you look again at [the instructions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)
you linked to, you'll find:

> 5.1   Easy Build and Install
>
> Issue the following commands in the shell (don't type $; that represents the shell's prompt):
>
> Select your configuration options and invoke ./bootstrap.sh again without the --help option. Unless you have write permission in your system's /usr/local/ directory, you'll probably want to at least use

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix
```

> to install somewhere else. Also, consider using the --show-libraries and --with-libraries=library-name-list options to limit the long wait you'll experience if you build everything. Finally,

```
$ ./b2 install
```

You haven't run `./b2 install`, and if your specified or default installation
`--prefix` requires root privilege to write - which is the case for the default `/usr/local` - then you need to run

```
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

After that, you'll see the boost headers and libraries under `/usr/local/include/boost`
and `/usr/local/lib` respectively, and you will not need to specify any explicit `-I`
or `-L` options to compile boost headers or link boost libraries, because `/usr/local/include`
is a default search path for the compiler and `/usr/local/lib` is a default search path for the
linker.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, I'll precise the question, but what I wanted to know by the 1st question is, "at equal version number", does it do the same to install the `all-dev` package than compiling it.

Comment: @s.k For a given boost version, the only difference between an `apt install libboost-all-dev` and installing from source is the possible difference in the installation directories, as explained in paragraph 3 of my answer.

Comment: @s.k Correction. There is one other difference. If you build and install with
prefix `/usr/local` from source and then wish to link and run your programs with
the boost *shared* (not static) libraries, you will need to run `$ sudo ldconfig`
(in any directory) to update the OS loader's dynamic linkage cache. `apt install
libboost-all-dev` will update the `ldconfig` cache automatically.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. I was having major issues with Boost until I found your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it solved my issues.

Comment: `sudo ./b2 install` is not installing anything for me at the moment, with boost 1.75.0 .  Running `./b2 install` as a local user does indeed install, but then permissions to /usr/local are denied.

Comment: I am so grateful for this tutorial!! Thank you!