# ROS melodic installation with Python 3 only and without messing up system libraries?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, ros

### Description of the procedure and issues:

I am following the installation guide there:
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

but:

1. `$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full` doesn't work:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    ros-melodic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-melodic-perception but it is not going to be installed    
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

   -> question 1.
2. `$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full` seems to work but it needs to install a whole bunch of packages (602 MB) - which I expected a little. When looking at these packages in details I can see:

   - More than 190 ros-something-packages: OK
   - A few new libraries: OK
   - More than 40 `python-<packages>` (which are definitely Python 2 packages): -> question 2.1
   - More than 80 `libboost-<something-system-libraries>`: -> question 2.2

### Related questions:

#### Question 1:

Do you know why?

#### Question 2.1:

How to force the usage of the Python 3 version of these packages?

#### Question 2.2:

For other purposes I build boost from sources ( [Building Boost from sources on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647596/building-boost-from-sources-on-linux) ).
Hence I fear that if I install ros with all these dependencies, the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) system libraries that come along with `ros` (which are all boost version **1.65**) will mess up with my personalized installation of boost libraries (which are in version **1.68**), especially when I would like to compile other softwares (I prefer to only have one version of these lib; i.e. the latest 1.68).
Is there a way to tell `ros` to use these already installed libraries (basically in `/usr/local/`)?

#### General informations:

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04: `4.15.0-43-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Python 3 version is: `3.6.7`

Answer (score 1):

In order for ROS Systems to works, it Needs dependencies at a minimum specific version.

You cannot use python 3 in installation since all tools are made with python 2.7+ But you can specify what python version to use when running or compiling packages By changing `ROS_PYTHON_VERSION` to 3.

I think you can use [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140998/compiling-source-into-a-deb-package) to convert your compiled source to a `.deb` file and install it over to prevent apt from interfering with your boost libraries

Comment: python 2 will be "soon" deprecated; https://pythonclock.org. It's time to upgrade imho.

Comment: would it be possible to "isolate" ros ecosystem like in a virtual environment?

Comment: @s.k I don't think isolating like virtualenv can be possible since ROS is using apt package manager, not pip. but what you can do (Hard Way of installing ROS) is compile everything from base that way you can use your own boost-Lib and use python-version of your choice. I never tried myself but you can check out their wiki

Comment: Or maybe a docker image where ros packages can be installed 'on-the-fly' based on the needs, like open_cv or others... But I'm unfortunately not used to docker.

Comment: Indeed docker can work as well but if you nodes become complex or you need to connect more than one system you might run into problems

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anaconda try this

`conda create -n ros python=3.7`

`conda activate ros`

`pip install rospy rospkg`

This worked for me.
Just install any other packages in the similar way pip install package-name

Comment: Hi Suraj and thanks for the contribution! Can you please add some explanation to your answer? It seems that the OP is particularly interested in understanding the causes, and also future readers might find it useful. Thank you and keep on stackoverflowing!